# Making a "About PC" boot opion in GRUB 2

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub2, grub, system-information

How could i make a boot option "About PC" in the GRUB boot menu that displays something like in the image running the newest version of GRUB i386-pc MBR everything uptodate.

Image slightly edited to update the kernel (which was 6.5.8-arch1-1 and its now uptodate) and remove the hostname and username.

[image: Neofetch and uname -a of the machine]

EDIT: All i need to get displayed on is a simple file contaning neofetch and uname -a outputs (with color if possible).

Comment: `I want ...` is not a question ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/cat.html#cat

Comment: Grub is used to select and boot an operating system, so it has not knowledge of most of the data: you may boot a different kernel (e.g. an old one, if the new has problem). Shell is also *relative*: every use may have own shell. Uptime at boot (so grub) has no sense. Hostname may be given dynamically. Or you can build the screen in Linux, and "upload" to GRUB, so with data from last boot. It depends what information do you want to convey (in a broad sense, not the details): what would be the user case?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Are you skilled in any programming language?

Frankly, figuring out things like *total number of packages installed* and *the version of your shell* would be hard to find out within GRUB. Since the kernel is not loaded yet (and GRUB can offer you a menu of kernel versions to select), the OS name and kernel version to run may not be decided yet at that point either.

So, the easiest way would probably be to make a script that runs at every boot, gathers the information you want to display, and renders it into a GRUB splash image. When you install updates and reboot, the information might be slightly out of date, until the splash image is updated at the next reboot.

Or if you want, you could hook the splash image update script to the most important update procedures: for example, you could make the post-installation of a new kernel automatically update the splash image too, by placing/linking the splash update script to `/etc/kernel/install.d` (or maybe `/etc/kernel/postinst.d`, if it is usable on Arch).

If you really wish to find out the information from the actual hardware at boot time, you should first familiarize yourself with the GRUB command prompt and see what its commands can find out: the `set` command can provide some basic information, `lsmmap` will describe the available RAM, `vbeinfo` should list available display modes (on i386-pc MBR; on UEFI, use `videoinfo` instead).

`lspci` would provide information that can be used to identify system components like the GPU and the chipset... but you would need to add some sort of a look-up table to provide human-readable descriptions instead of mostly ID numbers and generic device class identifications.

Querying the DMI information might give you the best chance to get a meaningful motherboard/system model description... but I'm not sure if GRUB has a command/module for that yet.

There used to be a project developing a bootable hardware detection tool, HDT. [Its webpage can still be found through the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160110082130/http://hdt-project.org/). It was designed mainly to be used with SYSLINUX and its variants, but might be adaptable to boot with GRUB too.